# Benifit of using action server between action client and controller?

Tags: ros

What are the benefits of using action server in middle of ros controllers and action client which sends some ros msgs(trajectory msgs) to the controllers? Although I know that by using the action client I can also check the status of the action, result and every client msgs sent to controllers. But are there any other advantages? I have tried the actionlib tutorials but didn't get the answer of this question so. 
Why can't I use ros publisher also in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publisher and subscriber are only used for contineous data stream like pointcloud or any other ros msgs, where the msgs is being contineiously published and can be subscribed. But since to control a robot and send a command to move its joint the command msgs like jointtrajectory msgs don't need to be sent continiously and for small period of time to move the robot, for this purpose action server and client is used.

In action server and client their is extra information like status, result and feedback which is used by the client to check wheather the joint commands sent has been accomplished by the robot or not, if yes client stops sending more joint msgs to the robot, same like when u send a move command to ur hands u dont send those commands contineously as u get the imformation that ur hand has reached the position where u want to place, u stop those commands. And publisher and subscriber is like publisher is ur eye which continiously sends image to ur brain and brain subscribes to them continiously and does its work.